# Some unknown exception in Android - App crashed with nothing in Logcat

Tags: java, android, android-studio

This exception spent me lots of time.
When user press a button , app will send two http request. 
`PMNetworkOperation.getSourceDataAppList()` and `PMVendorNetWork.getInstance().getVendorDownloadedAppList()`, both of them are async request. After request completing, they will use the below methods to save the data.

```
static public void setVendorAppList(ArrayList appList) {
    MixAppListHandler.vendorAppList = appList;
    mixAppList();
}

static public void setSourceAppList(ArrayList appList) {
    MixAppListHandler.sourceAppList = appList;
    mixAppList();
}
```

The method `mixAppList()` :

```
static private synchronized void mixAppList() {
    if (requestFlag != 1 ) {
        requestFlag ++;
    } else {
        requestFlag = 0;
        // mix data

        ...
    }
}
```

When the `requestFlag` is equal to `1`, `MixAppListHandler` will execute datas. These all data are static.

The question is when first request complete , after `requestFlag` modified to `1`, the variables window show `Collecting data` and then `Disconnect …`. After that my app closed  on my mobile with nothing output in Logcat. My IDE is Android Studio 1.0.1.

Is there any one can help me to solve this question? Thanks.

Comment: Try to run on debug mode

Comment: @Daryn thanks for your help. Of course I am on debug mode, when app run to `requestFlag ++;` , it is supposed to return , but it crashed.

Answer (score 0):

It is a known issue in early version of Android Studio. It has been fixed.